# Vm Instance on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

We own a VM instances in Google Cloud with ubuntu OS but suddenly we cannot connect to the instance via SSH. I have checked the Firewall and the port is enabled for all of the instances.

Watching the logs we are getting the error UFW BLOCK.

Please, could you gide me what to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone installed [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) but forgot to allow tcp:22 for SSH

You will have to connect to your instance using the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) and allow SSH

`sudo ufw allow ssh`

Comment: Greetings, inf fact there was something that unset the UFW rule. I found an startup script that let me set a user and password to connect to the instance via serial console. Thanks for you answer.